# Split 2D Array in C++/C to sub array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D Array `C[100][10]`,I want to split it column by column and insert in 1D Array like below :

`C[100][10]`  split to `C[0:100][0]` , `C[0:100][1]` , ... , `C[0:100][10]`
and the insert splited arrays to 1D array like : `A[100] =C[0:100][0]`

I can do all of that with for-loops but take long time and time is critical for my project.
is there any way to solve this problem excluding  for-loop

Comment: Is this C++ or C? The solution may be very different in C and C++.

Comment: You only need to do `for` in `for`. Does this really spend lots of time?

Comment: You should store the array as C[10][100]. Then you can access each subarray with C[i]. This kind of memory access should be a bit faster.

Comment: Quote: "I can do all of that with for-loops ..." Then post that code so that we can see what you are doing. That will also make the question more clear. Currently we don't even know the type of data.

Comment: @4386427 In C++

Comment: @Yves yes spend lots of time, My time unit is millisecond

Comment: @Alexanov ok, C++ then ... (C tag removed). You still need to post your current "slow" solution

Comment: If you don't want explicit `for` loops, you can use some of the [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) functions.

Comment: @Bob can you say me how can i use for my purpose?

Comment: This should not spend too much time. I guess the time is spent on object-copy. If so, you can simply use pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array of sub arrays like:

```
std::array<std::array<TYPE, 100>, 10> C;
```

Then the elements of each sub array are consecutively stored in memory and operations are faster.
[std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) provides copy operator

```
std::array<TYPE, 100> A = C[i];
```

Comment: Thank you,your solution is very useful but if i want to access to one column how can i do that?

Comment: @Alexanov If you can prepare the above array of array, you can also prepare vector of vector. Then you can split the matrix within ~1 msec by `std::move` like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GqxO63Uv6B1Xq2Ou). Why not do that ?

Comment: @Hiroki I saw your solution, can you say me how can I access to one row or column with vector? give me an example if it is possible for you , to show vector like `c[0:100][1]` or `c[1][0:10]`

Comment: @Alexanov `_1th_column`, ..., `_10th_column` in my answer are all `std::vector<Foo>`. Thus we can access each element of each column like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8d8tixQhjtPBLFQg). Could you please point it out if I misunderstand your problem :).

Comment: @Hiroki I have matrix `c[100][10]` .I want to split `2d` array and replace in `1D`array. first, split c from row  like `A=c[1][0:10]`T second, split c from column like `B=[0,100][1]`

Comment: @Alexanov Ah I see. I think that one possible approach would be using `std::valarray` with `std::slice`. Using it, you can access both rows and columns as a single vector. (But slow? I don't know it.)

Comment: @Hiroki is it possible to make an example?

Comment: @Alexanov How about [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XArsDcV7lDk39lnC)? I defined a simple matrix class with`std::vector` and column-major instead of `std::valarray`. This matrix class has member functions to get accessors to rows and columns without object-copy. This is my quick implementation and please be careful with dangling :). Simple [wrapping](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LTv9pFiI6ac16nqO) by lambdas also works.

Comment: @Hiroki your example is not clear for me. My problem is obvious.If we have matrix 2*3 with rand number in cells how can i access to row and column?

Comment: @Hiroki sorry but i have to say yes
I want very simple example